# Batch spelling correction request - onlick -> onclick on this 140 posts

Tags: support, status-completed, spelling

Batch spelling correction request - **onlick** -> **onclick** on this 140 posts

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onlick

<sub>***ps***: sorry if this report looks too offensive to someone</sub>

Comment: onlick - hilarious

Comment: Are you sure all of those are syntax errors? Some may be about designing an escort webpage...

Comment: Joke aside, what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed all the titles, since those are "in your face" .. but I don't see the point of changing the bodies -- that's also much more dangerous.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("a").onlick(function() {
    alert("Yummy");
});
```

In seriousness, just go through and edit them manually - pretty much all of those posts have other things (e.g. code formatting) that need editing too.

Already done a couple myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

What if this was the original mistake someone made? The question would no longer be right. Any changes to question titles or post bodies should always be done manually.